# Regex only numbers only with dot, no comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to build a regex expression for numbers, only separated with dot, comma is forbidden.

I've tried this code

```
^(\d+|\d+\.\d{1,4})[1-5]$
```

but it doesn't help for this rules:

> ***minimum***: one number 1 to 9
>   ***maxmimum***: five numbers 0.0001 or 12345
>   ***range***: 0.0001 to 99999

allowed examples:

> 12345
>   1234.1
>   123.12
>   12.345
>   1.2345   1
>   0.1
>   0.01
>   0.001
>   0.0001

thanks

Comment: Show your attempts..

Comment: ^(\d+|\d+\.\d{1,4})[1-5]$

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex. Negative lookahead at the start asserts that there isn't `99999.<any-num>` or only `0.one or more zeros` present.

```
^(?!99999\.\d|0+(?:\.0+)?$)\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mO6pD2/1)

Comment: cool, this looks great, I was looking for a generator source like this. Thank you.

Comment: @AvinashRaj as you can see from the OP's profile, he's already in common with [greenleaves](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4181097/jeldin)

Comment: question was closed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400209/regex-only-numbers-separated-with-dot